# Why does the 'useState' hook invoke the initial state when it's a function reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React has a hook called [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), which is used when adding state to functional components.

#### The [Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) states:

> **useState**:
>
> ```js
> const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
> ```
>
> Returns a stateful value, and a function to update it.
>
> During the initial render, the returned state (`state`) is the same as the value passed as the first argument (`initialState`).
>
> The `setState` function is used to update the state. It accepts a new state value and enqueues a re-render of the component.

#### The [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) states:

> **What do we pass to `useState` as an argument?**
>
> The only argument to the `useState()` Hook is the initial state. Unlike with classes, the state doesn’t have to be an object. We can keep a number or a string if that’s all we need. In our example, we just want a number for how many times the user clicked, so pass `0` as initial state for our variable. (If we wanted to store two different values in state, we would call `useState()`twice.)

#### Unexpected behaviour:

However, I've noticed some strange, *seemingly undocumented*, behaviour.

If I try to use the `useState` hook to store a function as state, **react will invoke the function reference**. e.g.

```js
const arbitraryFunction = () => {
    console.log("I have been invoked!");
    return 100;
};

const MyComponent = () => {

    // Trying to store a string - works as expected:
    const [website, setWebsite] = useState("stackoverflow"); // Stores the string
    console.log(typeof website);                             // Prints "string"
    console.log(website);                                    // Prints "stackoverflow"

    // Trying to store a function - doesn't work as expected:
    const [fn, setFn] = useState(arbitraryFunction);         // Prints "I have been invoked!"
    console.log(typeof fn);                                  // Prints "number" (expecting "function")
    console.log(fn);                                         // Prints "100"

    return null; // Don't need to render anything for this example...
};
```

When we call `useState(arbitraryFunction)`, react will invoke `arbitraryFunction` and use its return value as the state.

#### As a workaround:

We can store functions as state by wrapping our function reference in another function. e.g.

```js
const [fn, setFn] = useState(() => arbitraryFunction)
```

I haven't yet come across any real-world reasons to store functions as state, but it seems weird that somebody made the explicit choice to treat function arguments differently.

This choice can be seen in multiple places throughout the [React codebase](https://github.com/facebook/react):

```js
initialState = typeof initialArg === 'function' ? initialArg() : initialArg;
```

#### Why does this seemingly undocumented feature exist?

I can't think of any good reasons why anybody would want/expect their function reference to be invoked, but perhaps you can.

If this is documented, where is it documented?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state

Comment: @tkausl Brilliant, I'm not sure how I missed this

Comment: This is very interesting! I learned a thing!

Comment: @tkausl that's an answer, not a comment - post it as an answer and watch your rep grow :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

> #### Lazy initial state
>
> The initialState argument is the state used during the initial render.
>   In subsequent renders, it is disregarded. If the initial state is the
>   result of an expensive computation, you may provide a function
>   instead, which will be executed only on the initial render:
>
> ```
> const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
>   const initialState = someExpensiveComputation(props);
>   return initialState;
> });
> ```

Passing a callback to `setState` [also calls the callback, but for a different reason](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

> #### Functional updates
>
> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a
>   function to setState. The function will receive the previous value,
>   and return an updated value. Here’s an example of a counter component
>   that uses both forms of setState:
>
> ```
> function Counter({initialCount}) {
>   const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
>   return (
>     <>
>       Count: {count}
>       <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
>       <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
>       <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
>     </>
>   );
> }
> ```