# React useState arg function vs. value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

In doing

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState)
```

Why does it matter if I pass a value vs. function that returns a value? Should I always pass the function so it doesn't re-run?

```
  const initialState = foos.reduce((acc, f) => {
    console.log('re-runs on render')
    // ...
  }, {})
```

vs.

```
  const initialState = () => {
    console.log('will only run once')
    return foos.reduce((acc, f) => {
      // ...
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the 'useState' hook invoke the initial state when it's a function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59983813/why-does-the-usestate-hook-invoke-the-initial-state-when-its-a-function-refer)

Answer (score 1):

The function version of this is used to initialize a value of initial state that might be expensive to compute - for example, you might use it to start a fetch of a resource that you only want to run once per component instance.

If you don't need to lazily initialize a state value, just use the value itself. The difference will be really minimal unless you really need the lazy initialization.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a function, the function will only be executed once. If you pass something else it will be recomputed on each render, but won't trigger any change or rerender.